# r ggplot: multiple geoms and scales (which scale overides which geom?)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I intended to color lines in pink, and points in yellow. I don't want to use colour argument in respective geom(), I want to use scale to change colour.

```
p3 <- ggplot(dfcc,aes(x = yr, y = mean)) +
      geom_line(aes(color = '')) +
      geom_point(aes(color = ''))
p3 + scale_colour_manual(values =c('pink', 'yellow'))
```

This gives this plot, both lines and points are not in the right colours.
[image]

Hence, I have two questions

1. can I use "scale_colour_manual" to change the line and point colors in one go?
2. if having multiple geoms and multiple scales, how does the system know which scale applies to which geom?

Any help and explanation would be much appreciated!

Comment: re 1. I can't reproduce this; both approaches produce the same plot

Comment: @user20650 ohh yes, you are correct, I tried again with a new session, and now both plots are the same. I have removed a question and some codes from the post. Thank you

Comment: thanks. re 2, to get more control you could name the colour aesthetic dummy variable rather than an empty string e.g. `geom_line(aes(color = 'a')) +  geom_point(aes(color = 'b'))` then name the values in `scale_colour_manual(values =c(b='red', a='yellow'))`

Comment: @user20650 thank you so much, your solution works! but when to use dummy variable, when to leave it blank? why they are different? or do you know of any book chapters to recommend to explain this?

Comment: The aesthetics should be mapped to *variables*, in this case, categorical variables. Then, use `scales_*_manual` to change the colors from ggplot's defaults to thee ones you want.

Comment: @Elizabeth ; I'd think that most use cases would not leave the variables blank; it is much clearer when reviewing code if you are explicit in matching the variables. As Rui mentions above, normally colours are matched to variables, but if wanting to set a single colour, as in your example, this would normally be done within the geom (but outside the aes call) rather than trying to use a single scale_manual call. Imo it is less confusing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use package `ggnewscale`.

```r
set.seed(2022)
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:20, y = cumsum(rnorm(20, 2)))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line(color = "pink", linewidth = 2) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  geom_point(color = "yellow", size = 3) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: hi, thank you for the answer, and sorry that I was not clear in the post, yes I know just putting colour argument in the geom() can define the colour. I intended to use scale to define colour. I have updated my post accordingly